# How to transform data having inconsistent data types in AWS glue jobs?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, aws-glue

I have a array that looks like this. I fetch cloud data using boto3 and save it in s3 bucket

[array](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qw4mg.png)

Resource, Actions can be both Array and string depending on the data

I want to query on additional_data and based on conditions i want to do transformations

I crawled over this data using crawler and created a dynamic frame using database and table name

```
S3bucket_node1 = glueContext.create_dynamic_frame.from_catalog(
    database="Raghav",
    table_name="Raghav",
    transformation_ctx="S3bucket_node1",
)
```

I even picked up the data directly from s3 bucket using

```
S3bucket_node1 = glueContext.create_dynamic_frame.from_options(
    format_options={"multiline": True},
    connection_type="s3",
    format="json",
    connection_options={
        "paths": ["s3://raghav-test-df/raghav3_removedcolon.json"],
        "recurse": True,
    },
    transformation_ctx="S3bucket_node1",
)
```

when i run

```
S3bucket_node1.printSchema()
```

it is giving incorrect schema that looks like
[schema](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uniUY.png)

And when i do

```
S3bucket_node1.count()
```

it is giving 74 results where as the actual elements are 69

Can someone please help me

Q- I want to use the data which is stored in s3 bucket in an array and transform the data based on conditions, i read somewhere pyspark doesn't work well with inconsistent nested data types
so i used apache spark using

```
sparkDF=spark.read.option("inferSchema", "true").option("multiline", "true").json("s3://abababaa/abaaa.json")
```

it is giving correct count but transforming the data with sql is too complex

Should i use any other technique?

I tried using Pyspark for transformations but it is giving incorrect count and schema, maybe because pyspark doesn't work well with inconsistent data types